# Javascript prevent form submission

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, sql

I have a loop that checks if 44 fields are null, and displays an error message for those that are null. The issue I'm having is that even if there are null fields, the form submits after about 2 seconds. How can I prevent form submission if an error is triggered?

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Table1_1", FormMethod.Post, new { onsubmit = "return validateit()", name = "myForm" }))
{



function validateit() {


var count = 0;
var track = 0;
      for (var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
          var x = document.forms.myForm[fields[i][0]].value;
          if (x === null || x === "" || x === "    ") {
              count++;
              document.getElementById("demo" + (i + 1)).innerHTML = "<font style='color:red';>Error: " + fields[i][1] + "</font>";
              track++;
          }
          else {
              document.getElementById("demo" + (i + 1)).innerHTML = "";
              track++;
          }
          if (count > 0 && track > 43) {
                      return false;
          }
      }
```

Comment: Have you actually placed a breakpoint on your return false line to make sure it gets hit?

Comment: Why are you testing against `null`? Especially with an identity comparator? An empty input element's `value`, if empty, will not be `null`, it will be the empty string.

Comment: It does not, and I'm not sure why. There are 44 fields getting checked. I replaced the return false with an alert to see if it was entering that if, and got no alert.

Comment: Use event.preventDefault(). Check this link.. http://www.javascripter.net/faq/eventpreventdefault.htm

Comment: When are you calling this code to check the inputs? If it is on onsubmit of the form like <form onsubmit="Checkform()">, try writing <form onsubmit="return Checkform()">

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $('.form').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var formCheck = false;
        //check the form here if it is true, send the form
        if(formCheck){
            $('.form').addClass('checked');
            $('.checked').removeClass('form');
            $('.checked').submit();
        }
    });
});
```

Other better approaches would be HTML5 form validation using `required` : http://www.sitepoint.com/html5-form-validation/

Comment: Doesn't work if the form is submitted without clicking the submit button. You will want to bind the submit event to the form, but will need to unbind the event when you force a submit after checking the form.

Comment: You're recent edit is binding the submit function to the submit button, it needs to be bound to the form, and then you need to take into account the necessity to unbind the event when you force the submit as I noted above. Otherwise when you run `$("#form").submit()`, the submit event will be triggered again.